# Saving Files in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to save some screen dumps to internal storage for debugging purposes, but I can't seem to get access to them. When I call FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath(), I get a path that looks something like this:

/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/

But I can't see this folder in the Android File Transfer tool, so I can't drag the files to my Mac. I also tried attaching them to an email using the Message class, but for some reason the attachments never showed up. I notice that a lot of applications store data in folders like this:

```
/Android/data/com.doubletwist.androidplayer/
```

If I try to create a folder like this, I run into two problems. First, it's not platform independent. (This doesn't matter much because I'm just doing this for debugging.) Second, it doesn't work. I get an error telling me I need to use the directory returned by FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath()

Is there any way I can save files to a folder that I can actually retrieve them from? It would be more helpful if I had a platform-independent way, but any way that works is fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

File system is a very "unportable" notion. By default app home is a private folder which some mobile OS's including Android 4+ keep private and inaccessible.

Android has a concept of "sdcard" which used to be a physical storage where you could write anything in any directory without a problem. This is no longer applicable for later versions of Android but you can read from the sdcard directory and detect it.

[FileSystemStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html) has an API to get roots and their types, if you have an sdcard type you can read from there. You can use the [FileTree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/FileTree.html) to see the file hierarchy as exposed to your application which can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It sounds like I can only write to a single directory that no one else can see. Still, other Android apps have the ability to write to directories on the /Android/data/<packageName>/ path. That would be very nice to have. As it is, I can't even use my mail program to attach files that I create, because it can't see them. I'm not as familiar with other platforms, but it would be very useful if CodenameOne provided a method to create/return a user directory that others could see.

Comment: That's not what I said see the "sdcard" paragraph.

Comment: Maybe we're misunderstanding each other. The "sdcard" paragraph tells me that I can't write to the sdcard. The files I want to attach are files I created, so I can only save them to a directory that my mail program can't see.

Comment: You can't write to any directory but you can read from any directory. You can write to directories specific to your app. I don't recall the exact semantics since it's Android specific.